# If I have a char array containing strings with a null byte (\0) terminating each string, how would I add another string onto the end?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have a character array that contains strings, with each string terminated with a null byte, e.g. `{'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '\0'}`.

I want to add a string to the end of this array without removing the final `\0`, giving me (e.g.) `{'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '\0', 'n', 'e', 'w', '\0'}`.

I believe `strcat` from `string.h` will remove the final null byte, so that doesn't work in this case.

I've also tried this, but it didn't seem to work:

```
char str[20] = {'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
char new_str[6] = "Array";
str[8] = new_str;
```

Comment: None of the string functions will work with an array that has null bytes in the middle, since they consider the string to end at the first null byte.

Comment: There's no standard library function that deals with null-separated char arrays like this. Can you talk about edge cases more? Does the array `{'a', '\0', '\0'}` represent the string `"a"` and then the empty string `""`? How should the code know that there's another string after the first null terminator instead of the end of the array?

Comment: `memcpy` or `strcpy`could be your friend. But you need to find the destination address manually

Comment: how do ypu know how many strings you have in the char array? A sideband counter? A double nul character?/empty string  Exact array size?

Comment: You cannot "add [] onto the end" of an array in C.  Arrays have the same length for their entire lifetime.  You could create a *new* larger array, and copy original and new data into it, but that's not the same thing as adding to an existing array.  You could also copy data into existing elements of an array if there are any whose current values you do not need, but that's not adding onto the array, it's modifying (perhaps adding onto) its logical *content*.

Comment: I don't understand what actually is causing difficulty here. Can you think of a way to get a pointer to the place in memory immediately after the last null terminator? Can you think of a way to copy a null-terminated string to a place in memory? If you put these two things together, do you see how it would solve the problem? (Is there a reason why this way of breaking down the problem, is not obvious?)

Comment: "I've also tried this, but it didn't seem to work:" - Okay, so it seems like you already broke the problem down that way, and understood how to do the first part (although you've mis-counted the desired position - or maybe you forgot that arrays are 0-indexed?), but not the second. I'm not sure how it's possible to be familiar with `strcat`, but not `strncpy` nor `strcpy`.

Comment: Given that there may be multiple strings in the array, how do you know where the last string ends? If the array has been fully initialized, so there are zero bytes after the last string, and none of the strings that will be recorded in it is an empty string, then the end position can be indicated by a null byte after the null byte that terminates the last string. Is that the case? If not, how do you know where the end is?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Re “You cannot "add [] onto the end" of an array in C”: The question does not ask to add to the end of an array. It asks to add to the “end”, which can be “the end of the strings,” not “the end of the array,” and it shows an example where there is available space in the array after the end of the strings in it.

Comment: Do not confuse array *initializers* in declarations with *assignments* in expressions.  C does not have whole-array assignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the end *could* be the end of the sequence of strings.  It's unclear whether the OP is making the distinction you are, and my comment draws their attention to the fact that there is a distinction to be made.  It also emphasizes that even for the case of adding to the logical content, you have to work within the original size of the array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I read quite explicitly in the question: "I want to add a string to the end of this array".

Comment: `str[8] = new_str;` is wrong in C. 1) you can't copy strings like that. 2) Index 8 is wrong because you have to start index from zero; But `strcpy(&str(7), new_str);` would do the job in this specific case... But for generic code it's too simple.

Comment: I vote to close because we need more information. Most important is: How can we know the number of strings?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, and it shows an array of characters in text, not C code. The C code shows an array defined with additional space available. So OP knows the space is needed, and these various comments sniping about trivialities are nuisances that do not help. Once OP specifies how the end of the strings will be known, the question can be answered, and then an answer can mention incidentally that space is needed.

Comment: "with a null byte (\0) terminating each string" == hello\0\0 (== sandwich with bread)    Because a string is null byte terminated by definition. The null byte is the end delimiter. Your post mixes the concept of string with other things. Would be better to speak about concatenating two (or more) objects in memory ("that by chance could be strings...") with the conditions you talk about. Putting in place the string type imposes twists in your post as that anything that manages strings would reject impossible strings like concatenations of characters with null characters in between.

Comment: I wrote and self-answered a proper version of the question [on Codidact](https://software.codidact.com/posts/291111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a pointer to the element after the null byte, and use use that as the target of `strcpy()`.

```
char str[20] = {'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'};
char new_str[6] = "Array";
strcpy(&str[strlen(str)+1], new_str);
```

For the more general case, you need to keep track of the last string in the array, so you can find the element after its null terminator.

Comment: The problem states there is an array that contains strings, plural, and gives an example (in the first sentence, not the later code) with two strings. Finding the first null byte is insufficient.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting DV'd.  It is a feasible approach to the problem, and the example is based directly on one presented in the question.  However, the details provided do not constitute a *complete* solution for the case where there is initially more than string in the array.  One does need something more than `strlen()` here (maybe a count of the current number of strings, so as to make an appropriate number of `strlen()` calls, for example).

Comment: @JohnBollinger There are many things that don't work here: this doesn't account for the case of multiple strings already being in the buffer (or *no* strings!) - it will be necessary to track the "end of the data" separately. This also doesn't account for potential buffer overruns, and as such it's dangerous to show such code, especially to an apparent beginner. But beyond all of that, it's attempting to answer a question **that should be closed instead**, as it is too vague and unfocused. The comments demonstrate that OP has not clearly identified *what* the actual problem to solve is.

Comment: For the specific example this is a fine solution. But for the generic task, i.e. "Add a string to the end of char array containing several strings" we need more complex code

Comment: Suggest some type of sentinel at the end of the last string. Zero initializing works, but space must be reserved for the double nul-char at the end of the string. If the last string only has a single nul-char on the array boundary, there is no way to distinguish it being the end of the last string without preserving the original array size for comparison.  Rather wonky storage setup, but hey, it's C, you have the freedom to make it work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin FYI, this is basically how Unix implements the data that `argv` and `envp` point to. I think they might even have the double-null sentinel at the end, but not sure. I don't think any of this is in the spec, it's just the traditional implementation.

Comment: @Barmar, yep, as well as all the `execl..` functions where a sentinel `NULL` is used as the final pointer. Makes it simple to loop `while (ptr) { ... }`. But when rolling-your-own, it takes care to ensure the sentinel is placed appropriately -- especially when removing elements. (where the confusion in my comment arose I was picturing cramming multiple strings into a single character array -- slightly different than the question of `char **` and `char *[]`)

Answer (score 1):

If the remainder of the array is zeroed out (which it should be in your example), the easy(-ish) thing would be to start at the end and count backward until you find the first non-0 byte, then your new start position would be that index (or pointer) plus 2:

```
for ( size_t i = 18; i > 0; --i ) // save room for that last terminator
{
  if ( arr[i] ) // character is non-zero
    index = i + 2;
}
```

then you could use `strcpy` to append the new string to the end (assuming you've made sure there's room first):

```
strcpy( &arr[index], "new" );
```

*Buuuuuuuttttt...*

This method is *guaranteed* to cause heartburn, especially if you want to modify anything but the last string.  If you're determined to keep all your strings in a single `char` array, then you should create a secondary table to keep track of each string's starting index, length, and whatever else data you're interested in; that will make it a lot easier to find and append strings:

```
char strspace[SOME_SIZE] = {0}; 

/**
 * Create a table to track your strings
 */
struct st { 
  size_t index;
  size_t len;
} st[SOME_SIZE];

size_t count = 0;

...

st[count].index = count > 0 ? st[count-1].index + st[count - 1].len : 0;
st[count].len = strlen( newStr ) + 1;
strcpy( &strspace[st[count++].index], newStr );
```

I'm preserving the 0 terminator in this case to make it easier to use the regular string library on the data stored in the array, such as

```
strcpy( someString, &strspace[st[i].index] );
strlen( &strspace[st[x].index );
```

etc.  Not storing the terminator would free up a little space, but you'll have to do extra work if you want to be able to use the string library on these strings.  That's up to you.

If you have to modify or remove strings in the middle of the array, then you'll want to keep track available blocks in the table as well, maybe consolidate empty space when necessary.

Unless you *really need* to keep all your strings in a single contiguous array, I'd create an array of pointers, then allocate memory for each individual string:

```
char **strs = malloc( sizeof *strs * num_strings );
...
strs[i] = malloc( sizeof *strs[i] * (strlen( newStr ) + 1 );
if ( strs[i] )
  strcpy( strs[i], newStr );
```

Don't have to worry about where anything starts or stops, easy to extend, easy(-ish) to sort, just a lot easier to deal with in many respects.

Comment: The "scan backwards for a non-null" approach also discards the possibility of storing empty strings.